# Как получить ширину строки в GDI+

Tags: delphi, gdi+

Как в GDI+ сделать аналог функции TextWidth? Пытаюсь адаптироваль для Delphi найденную [тут](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2118/Bypass-Graphics-MeasureString-limitations) функцию, он она падает на MeasureCharacterRanges с ошибкой "(GDI+ Error) One of the arguments passed to the method was not valid.". Как это исправить?

```
Function MeasureDisplayStringWidth(Graphics: IGPGraphics; Text: String; Font: IGPFont): Extended;
Var
  StringFormat: IGPStringFormat;
  R: TGPRectF;
  CharRanges: IGPCharacterRanges;
  CharRange: TGPCharacterRange;
  Regions: IGPRegions;
Begin
  R.Initialize(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
  CharRanges := TGPArray<TGPCharacterRange>.Create(1);
  CharRange.Initialize(0, 2);
  CharRanges[0] := CharRange;
  StringFormat:= TGPStringFormat.Create;
  StringFormat.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(CharRanges);
  Regions := Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges(Text, Font, R, StringFormat);
  Regions[0].GetBounds(R, Graphics);
  Result:=R.Right+1;
End;
```

Comment: `MeasureCharacterRanges` — это правильный путь. А вот в вопросе мало информации. Как именно вылетает? Что говорит? Чему равны аргументы при этом?

Comment: Говорит "(GDI+ Error) One of the arguments passed to the method was not valid." Какой тут может быть не валидный агрумент? Вроде всё инициализировано.

Comment: А, всё, разобрался. Ошибка была на самом деле тут `CharRange.Initialize(0, 2);` нужно написать `CharRange.Initialize(0, Length(Text));` тогда всё работает правильно. Инициализировал 2 символа, а передавал 1

Comment: Вот и хорошо. Напишите в ответ, а? Может, кому-то пригодится. И добавьте ошибку в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так работает корректно, может кому пригодится:

```
Procedure MeasureDisplayStringWidthAndHeight(Graphics: IGPGraphics; Text: String; Font: IGPFont; Var Width, Height: Extended);
  Var
    StringFormat: IGPStringFormat;
    R: TGPRectF;
    CharRanges: IGPCharacterRanges;
    CharRange: TGPCharacterRange;
    Regions: IGPRegions;
  Begin
    R.Initialize(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
    CharRanges := TGPArray<TGPCharacterRange>.Create(1);
    CharRange.Initialize(0, Length(Text));
    CharRanges[0] := CharRange;
    StringFormat:= TGPStringFormat.Create;
    StringFormat.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(CharRanges);
    Regions := Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges(Text, Font, R, StringFormat);
    Regions[0].GetBounds(R, Graphics);
    Width:=R.Width; //ширина без отступов, если нужно с отступами R.Right
    Height:=R.Height; //можно так же получить из IGPFont
  End;
```